# Pandas apply function does not assign values to the colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am trying to put this logic on pandas dataframe

```
IF base_total_price > 0
    IF base_total_discount = 0
        actual_price = base_total_price
   
     IF base_total_discount > 0
            actual_price = base_total_price +base_total_discount

IF base_total_price = 0
     IF base_total_discount > 0
          actual_price = base_total_discount
     IF base_total_discount = 0
          actual_price = 0
```

so I wrote these 2 apply functions

```
#for all entries where base_total_price > 0
df_slice_1['actual_price'] = df_slice_1['base_total_discount'].apply(lambda x: df_slice_1['base_total_price'] if x == 0 else df_slice_1['base_total_price']+df_slice_1['base_total_discount'])

#for all entries where base_total_price = 0
df_slice_1['actual_price'] = df_slice_1['base_total_discount'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else df_slice_1['base_total_discount'])
```

When i run the code I get this error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 20, placement implies 1
```

I know that it is trying to put more values in one column but I do not understand why is this happening or how can I solve this problem. All I need to do is to update the dataframe with the new column `actual_price` and I need to calculate the values for this column according to the above mentioned logic. Please suggest me a better way of implementing the logic or correct me

Comment: I know it seems pythonic but that's not the correct way to write conditionals in pandas, think of set based operations. That would be better if you, as Trenton has said is provide a [mcve] with your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data would have been useful. Please try use `np.select(condtions, choices)`

```
 Conditions=[(df.base_total_price > 0)&(df.base_total_discount == 0),(df.base_total_price > 0)&(df.base_total_discount > 0),\
    (df.base_total_price == 0)&(df.base_total_discount > 0),\
    (df.base_total_price == 0)&(df.base_total_discount == 0)]
choices=[df.base_total_price,df.base_total_price.add(df.base_total_discount),df.base_total_discount,0]
df.actual_price =np.select(Conditions,choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question simply by using iterrows. Thanks everyone who responded